# Setuid shell script

Tags: linux

Need some help on passing argv, so the shell script can be run as /usr/local/bin/script.sh user domain

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

   if( argc == 3 )
   {
      char *user = argv[1];
      char *domain = argv[2];
      setuid(0);
      system("/usr/local/bin/somescript.sh user domain");
      return 0;
   }
   else if( argc > 3 )
   {
      printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("One argument expected.\n");
   }
}
```

After compiling, i executed the code:

```
[user@server:/usr/local/bin]#c_setuid hello hello.com
Invalid username/domain
[user@server:/usr/local/bin]#
```

I suspect the string hello & hello.com wasn't pass to /usr/local/bin/somescript.sh. Anyone can help?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: `setuid` scripts are disabled for a reason. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot become root by calling `setuid(0)`.

You are passing the literal "user" and "domain" strings to the script. C is not Perl, variables are not magically interpolated into strings.

You need to create the string passed to system in runtime:

```
char cmd[100];
sprintf(cmd, "/usr/local/bin/somescript.sh %s %s", user, domain);
system(cmd);
```